# Application has stopped when click button login with ButtonLogin from android retrofit

Tags: android

I want making application login with Retroit. but the application always showing like keep force stop
[image]

I dont know whats happening on here

here is my function of login

```
    private void SignInNow() {
        final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        dialog.setMessage("Please wait.....");
        dialog.show();

        Call<Users> call = apiInterface.performLogin(username.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Users>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Users> call, Response<Users> response) {
                String result = response.body().getResponse();
                if(result.equals(true))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Logged in Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    dialog.dismiss();


                }
                else if(result.equals(false)) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Logged in failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Users> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Something went wrong, Please Try Again !",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

here is my API (Register working properly)

```
public interface ApiInterface {
    @GET("login.php")
    Call<Users> performLogin(
            @Query("username") String username,
            @Query("password") String password
    );

    @GET("register.php")
    Call<Users> performRegister(
            @Query("Name") String Name,
            @Query("username") String username,
            @Query("password") String password
    );
}
```

And this is users

```
public class Users {
    @SerializedName("response")
    private String Response;
    private String Name;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public String getResponse() {
        return Response;
    }


}
```

did i miss something on here? like wrong API or function? thanks

Comment: There is definitely a stacktrace in your log. Post it as well if you don't find the reason there

Comment: now already solve but always throwing as false

Comment: show us your Logcat too.

Comment: 2021-02-07 10:40:34.230 16228-16228/com.example.loginretrofit I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;

Comment: 2021-02-07 10:40:34.232 16228-16228/com.example.loginretrofit I/art: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.loginretrofit-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.loginretrofit-1/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]